# tcping doesn't work but DNS: Could not find host error

Tags: networking, ping

I need to measure Windows remote desktop latency for various cases, e.g. over a VPN, over a SSH tunneling, direct connecting etc; For that I found that a tool called `tcping` is good for it.

So I download it https://elifulkerson.com/projects/tcping.php and tested if it works:

```
ssh -p 50022 -L 13389:localhost:3389 user@220.123.123.123
# so now I can RDP to the machine specifying `localhost:13389` on mstsc.exe
```

```
$ tcping.exe localhost:13389

DNS: Could not find host - localhost:13389, aborting
```

But as you can see it gets an error. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### How can I solve this problem?

> `tcping.exe localhost:13389`

Your syntax is wrong:

> `tcping [-tdsvf46] [-i interval] [-n times] [-w interval] [-b n] [-r times][-j depth] [--tee filename] [-f] destination [port]`

Source: [tcping/usage.txt at master · jtilander/tcping · GitHub](https://github.com/jtilander/tcping/blob/master/src/usage.txt)

Try:

```
tcping localhost 13389
```